# expand childs' heights to fill parent's div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a parent `col` with its height based on the viewport, and I have 3 rows as childs.

Parent's height should be splited for each child so that they take an equal part of the space available in the parent.

Giving the `height: 33%` is super lame and I cant figure out a way to do it properly.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="height: 25vh;">
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Question might be a duplicate, but I dont know how to properly formulate my request.

Comment: Why do you think this is not correct? I think it might works well with 33% `width`.

Comment: It might, but I'm pretty sure considering its web architecture there's a way to take 100% of space without number inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row{
  background: gray;
  margin: 1px 0px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 box" style="height: 25vh;">
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <!--Content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Try to use `display:flex`

Comment: That's it, I only need now to define sub-childs' heights on my side but its pretty straightforward, thanks !

Comment: @QuentinLaillé It's my pleasure :)